# predict function in R for a matrix

Tags: r, predict

So, I have 2 datasets, training and test. The training dataset is a 926x9 matrix. The first 8 columns represent the feature vector x and the last column represents single valued output y. The test data set 103x8 matrix. I am looking to perform linear regression on the same.

```
trainData <- read.table("./traindata.txt")
X <- as.matrix(trainData[,1:8])
Y <- as.matrix(trainData[,9])
relation <- lm(Y~X)
testData <- read.table("./testinputs.txt")
testX <- as.matrix(testData[,1:8])
testOutputForY <- predict(relation, newdata = data.frame(X = testX))
```

The warning message I get is 'newdata' had 103 rows but variables found have 926 rows. I am not sure as to what changes need to be made to get it working fine`enter code here`

Comment: To use `predict()` you really need to use a `data=` argument in your `lm()`. So the column names match up between your train data and test inputs? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. (We don't need your entire dataset, just enough it see what's really going on.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710992/applying-lm-and-predict-to-multiple-columns-in-a-data-frame

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380300/shortcut-using-lm-in-r-for-formula